Open or closed windows in a tornado?
Should one have the windows open or closed when a tornado is nearby? B.S. in Physics but very rusty in this day and age. I have always been taught that one should keep windows cracked open because of the pressure drop and thus cause breaking of windows (Bernoulli). The question comes to mind because I made sure I had air access into my house and attic before a tornado was extremely close meanwhile my neighbor lost a window from pressure drop, so we think. I know modern windows can handle a great deal of wind speeds, but storm spotter classes (IL) are suggesting not to open windows because the pressure change damage is false. Open for thoughts!

Note that MythBusters busted this myth in 2009. The effect is negligible, and the mess from rain and debris is much worse.

Why did people open their windows before a tornado hit their home?
There is a significant pressure drop inside a tornado - It can be about 10% lower than ambient. So, when a tornado passes over and around a house, there will be higher air pressure inside the house than outside. The old belief was that this pressure difference could blast out a wall, or even pop the house like an over-inflated balloon. So, the old recommendation was to open a window to allow the higher inside pressure to escape.
The idea wasn’t entirely crazy - Those pressure differences really do exist. But new and better research has shown that the old idea of the house exploding from internal pressure is just plain wrong. Plausible originally, but it turned out that this just isn’t the way structures fail in a tornado.
The best research was done by the National Wind Institute at Texas Tech in 1977. Here is what their website says:

Do houses explode in a tornado?
Buildings appear to "explode" when hit by a tornado. However, the
cause of the outward and upward movement of walls and roof is
wind-related, rather than induced by atmospheric pressure change. When
an opening appears in a windward* wall, such as when a piece of debris
breaks a window, winds enter the building and exert an outward
pressure on the walls causing the walls to be pushed outwards. This
gives the impression of an explosion.
Why is it no longer recommended to open a window when a tornado is
imminent?
While it is true that pressure on the roof can be relieved by opening
a window on the leeward* side of the house, the direction of an
attacking wind will be unknown. Even when the tornado approach
direction is known the winds of the tornado are spinning; so depending
on which part of the tornado passes over the house, the winds on the
wall could be from any direction. Opening a window on the "wrong" side
could be detrimental to the building and waste valuable time needed to
reach a place of safety. Additionally, most residences and commercial
buildings have enough natural venting to relieve any change in
atmospheric pressure which may occur. (One square foot of opening per
1000 cubic feet of volume will "vent" the atmospheric pressure change
effects of a severe tornado.) Finally, it is noted that severe winds
act on a building before the largest portion of the atmospheric
pressure change can become effective; hence, window failures or
failures of other components are likely to "open" the structure to a
greater degree than an open window would. Therefore, when a tornado is
approaching, the best action is to take shelter immediately.

You can read more from Texas Tech -
https://www.depts.ttu.edu/nwi/research/windprotection.php
So, your house is reasonably good at equalizing pressure whether you open a window or not, the worst punch from the wind hits before the low pressure does, and perhaps opening a window that might survive the punch could instead let in a damaging blast of air.
I very nearly drove my car into the April 27, 2011, Tuscaloosa tornado, which was the most damaging tornado in the 2011 Super Outbreak (362 confirmed tornadoes, with well over 300 fatalities). There was a lot of research done after this outbreak, and one new recommendation emerged, with a number of emergency/trauma doctors and meteorologists pushing for it. Unfortunately, the new recommendation did not get publicized as well as it deserved. What did they discover from researching injuries?
It can boost your odds of survival or avoid devastating trauma if you put on a motorcycle helmet, football helmet, or similar full-head protection.
Makes more sense than opening a window. Hope that helps you.
Edit:
Taken from my Quora answer:-
https://www.quora.com/Why-did-people-open-their-windows-before-a-tornado-hit-their-home/answer/Emory-Kimbrough

And that helmet is mobile protection like your phone, probably putting on a hefty coat even in the heat would be better than a tee and shorts sandals, too. Question this deals with tornado winds what if hurricanes and downbursts?

Your research states a 1977 report in the era when homes were drafty structures, now a large and growing proportion are virtually airtight and also more robustly fastened/clamped together. Worth seeing if the source has an update after fifty odd years.

Also, in the 70's air-conditioning installation mostly window units was rare and in most areas that were threatened by storms or tornados would have had the windows open for any whisky breeze. Very good answer by the way.

"Here is what their web site says" - please add a hyperlink! Also you can use blockquote syntax to format the part you're quoting.
